# How many permutations cover alternating/reverse alternating permutations?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Given integers $1$ through $2n$, let $S$ be set of ordering of integers that respect even alternating or reverse alternating permutations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation) up to length $2n$ ($2,4\dots,2n-2,2n$), $\overline{S}$ be set of orderings that violate alternating and reverse alternating permutations up to length $2n$ .

$$3<4>2<5>1<6>3$$
$$4>2<5>1<6>3<4$$
$$2<3>1<4>2$$
$$4<5>3<6>3$$
are examples of alternating and reverse alternating permutations respectively of length up to $6$ and are in $S$.

$$3>2>1<6>5>4>3$$
$$4>2>1<5<6>3<4$$
$$4>2>1<3<4$$
$$6>4>3<5<6$$
are not alternating or reverse alternating permutations and are in $\overline{S}$.

$|S\cup\overline{S}|=n!$.

How many permutation maps $\sigma_1$ through $\sigma_K$ does one need so that for every $s\in S$ there is a $\sigma_i$ where $i\in\{1,\dots,K\}$ such that $\sigma_i(s)\in\overline{S}$?